# How to add submenu on hover effect in left navigation in magento?

Tags: magento, navigation

I have vertnav/left.phtml file code,

```
 <div class="vertnav-container">

<div class="">

    <h4 class="no-display"><?php echo $this->__('Category Navigation:') ?></h4>

 <?php $store_categories = $this->toLinearArray($this->getStoreCategories()) ?>

  <?php if ($count = count($store_categories)): ?>

    <ul id="vertnav">

  <?php endif; ?>
     <?php foreach ($store_categories as $i => $_category): ?><?php $class = array() ?>
   <?php if ($count == 1): ?>
    <?php $class[] = 'only' ?>
     <?php elseif (! $i): ?>
     <?php $class[] = 'first' ?>
  <?php elseif ($i == $count-1): ?>
          <?php $class[] = 'last' ?>
    <?php if (isset($store_categories[$i+1]) && $this->isCategoryActive($store_categories[$i+1])) $class[] = 'prev'; ?>
 <?php if (isset($store_categories[$i-1]) && $this->isCategoryActive($store_categories[$i-1])) $class[] = 'next'; ?>
     <?php echo $this->drawOpenCategoryItem($_category, 0, $class) ?>
  <?php endforeach ?>
   <?php if ($count): ?>
    </ul>
 <?php endif; ?>
</div>
 </div>
```

and set System > Configuration > Catalog > Category Vertical Navigation to 2 as per my requirement, but now on mouseover on that displayed category subcategories should be shown

so how can i do customization to that and add hover effect code to this?

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

If you take a closer look at the `drawOpenCategoryItem` of the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation` you might notice that the method does a check whether the given category is part of the current category path. So only when this check returns `true`, the children categories of this category will be rendered. For other categories the script will not go into that part of the code.

This sounds to be case if I understand your question correctly.

```
    if (in_array($category->getId(), $this->getCurrentCategoryPath())){
        $children = $category->getChildren();
        $hasChildren = $children && $children->count();

        if ($hasChildren) {
            $htmlChildren = '';
            foreach ($children as $child) {
                $htmlChildren.= $this->drawOpenCategoryItem($child);
            }

            if (!empty($htmlChildren)) {
                $html.= '<ul>'."\n"
                        .$htmlChildren
                        .'</ul>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Additional to this information. The `drawOpenCategoryItem()` is never actually called upon in the whole PHP codebase.

So to have these rollover effects you need to have code that generates the full tree structure, or at least a big enough part of it. Regarding the `System > Configuration > Catalog > Category Vertical Navigation`. I guess you customized that yourself?

To give you a few pointers. You might want to have a look at the following methods. These are used for the rendering of the top menu and are actually doing the thing you are planning to implement.

`Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation::renderCategoriesMenuHtml()`
`Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation::_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml()`

Hopes this helps you getting things underway.